# Upload/download UIImage to Parse.com using REST API best practice

Tags: json, rest, parse-platform, uiimage, swift2

What is the best way to upload and download an image to Parse.com using REST API?

I tried to encode to base64, but can't seem to get it to cast back to UIImage I get the JSON `NSData`. Tried to decode back but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing and extensive research, I found the solution:

After you cast the `UIImage` to `NSData`, you need to encode to base64 String and then upload the image to Parse.com using REST API see [Using Swift in an iOS Application to Upload an Image to a RESTful API](http://paoloibarra.com/2014/10/11/Image-Upload-To-RESTful-API-Swift/).

Next stage when you call a GET request to Parse.com, use the below to decode the base64 and cast it back to `UIImage.`

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        if (error == nil) {
            do {
                let imageJSONDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]

                let base64String = imageJSONDictionary!["imageKey"] as! String

                let imageData:NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!

                 self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            } catch {

            }
        } else {
            print("ERROR: \(error)")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
```